# C# CSOM SPView ListItemCollection did not update after I add new field in the SP view

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

```
SPClientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx
Web SPWeb = SPClientContext.Web;
List SPlist_CSV = SPWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Supplier Master List");

View SPview_CSV = SPlist_CSV.Views.GetByTitle("_Data Pending Export to CSV");//oracle export field

SPClientContext.Load(SPview_CSV);
SPClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = SPview_CSV.ViewQuery;

ListItemCollection items = SPlist_CSV.GetItems(query);
SPClientContext.Load(items);
SPClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var item in items)
{
   //some field/item missing?
}
```

Hi, I using the code above to retrieve data from a SharePoint online. At first, it was working fine.

But, when I add in new column to the view `_Data Pending Export to CSV` on SharePoint online, I found out that the new added field are missing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found out its others issue, the lookup field over limit. What I did to fix it is to change my lookup field to single line of text field, then use workflow to fill the new single line of text field.